# How do I get my clicks to work on the website https://www.costcobusinessdelivery.com using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, partiallinktext

When I run this code in Selenium is simply sits there loading the web page forever. Is anyone able to get this code to work and bring me to the login form?

```
from selenium import webdriver;
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select;
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys;
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By;
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options;
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait;
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC;
import time;



browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.costcobusinessdelivery.com')

WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#header_sign_in"))).click()
```

After about 5 minutes of the webpage remaining unresponsive I get this error:

```
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-47279e187da7> in <module>
     11 
     12 browser = webdriver.Chrome()
---> 13 browser.get('https://www.costcobusinessdelivery.com')
     14 
     15 WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#header_sign_in"))).click()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    331         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    332         """
--> 333         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    334 
    335     @property

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)
```

Comment: is browser launched when you ran this code?

Comment: Yeah, the browser is launched and the website opens fine. However, it seems to be continually loading/frozen after that.

Comment: @jest3rz What is your next step?

Comment: @debanjanb to send.keys to the login form to login to the website. I can't access the login form though because the webpage is unresponsive and sits loading.

Comment: @jest3rz - I also reproduced page is unresponsive when automation script opens it. works fine on manual. I am also waiting to see the answer.

Comment: @AmitJain whats odd is the regular costco.com website works, albeit slowly.

Comment: @jest3rz => manually it works fast, page load time is fast.

Comment: @AmitJain Yeah, I meant with Selenium. Costco.com works but costcobusinessdelivery.com doesn't. Very odd

Comment: It's possible that costcobusinessdelivery.com restricts access for automation browsers. From what I understand, these sites can detect where traffic originates from, and they might block any traffic that is not sourced from manual clicks.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the link with text as **Sign In / Register** within the website https://www.costcobusinessdelivery.com/ you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Sign In / Register"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#header_sign_in"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='header_sign_in']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: costco_login]

Comment: the new code doesn't work, selenium sits on the www.costcobusinessdelivery.com webpage and never loads. After about 5 minutes I get this error:

TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.75)